# debug adding header in middleware laravel

Tags: laravel

i added header in middleware and i want to check in my controller that header that i set exists or not . the problem i cant watch headers in controller debugging? how can i do that? anyway use case for this is `cors` problem

this is my middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
}
```

and this is my controller:

```
public function action()
{
    dd(request()->headers->get("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")); //always null
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the `set` method:

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    return $next($request);
}
```

Then you can retrieve the header:

```php
public function action()
{
    dd(request()->headers->get("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")); // *
}
```